# Wix 'specified account already exists' on repair

Tags: wix, installation, wix3.9

I've read this:
[Windows msi: error 1316: the specified account already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975371/windows-msi-error-1316-the-specified-account-already-exists)

and this:
[Role of various GUIDs in WiX ("error: The specified account already exists")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206461/role-of-various-guids-in-wix-error-the-specified-account-already-exists)

And I didn't find any solution of my problem.

When I install app.msi all working fine. When I want to install again app.msi I use repair and all is fine. 
But when I change installer name from app.msi to app2.msi after repair click I've an error

["The specified account already exists"](http://oi62.tinypic.com/mrty6g.jpg)

Why it works like this and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: You may need to refine your question. You can't "install again" by doing a repair - a repair is a repair and will not reinstall anything other than btoken components. If you have a newer version of your setup then you need a major upgrade.

Comment: When I want repair existing installation, after I change name of my installer e.g. from app.msi to app_old.msi and I use app_old.msi for repair then this errors occurs. There isn't any newer version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allowed to change the filename of an installer after installation. Changing the filename requires to change the product code, and therefore requires recompilation of your installer.

What you are allowed to do is: build version 1 of your app, then build version 2. Version 2 is allowed to have a different filename than version 1 if it has a product code different from version 1.

This will lead you to 2 different behaviors of your installer:

- If you want version 2 to install side-by-side with version 1, then changing the product code is enough.
- If you want version 2 to upgrade version 1 (and therefore replace it), you'll need to implement a [major upgrade](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369786(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: "You are not allowed to change the filename of an installer after installation." Can you provide source for that bit of knowledge?