# Wix : "error 1316: the specified account already exists" on one server

Tags: wix

On my test machine, the setup installs/uninstalls without any problem. 
Also, I already have installed about 50 customers with this installer. 
It seems to be only my installer that has the problem (tried to install example msi, which worked)

- I tried the Microsoft Fixit tool for fixing corruption issues.
- I tried MsiZap from the windows development toolkit
- I tried searching the registry manually for leftover keys ...

Nothing worked.

Does anyone know exactly what this error means, and I mean by that, what does it check (registry key? ...) to respond with this error?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that somewhere in your WiX you have something like a WiX util CreateUser and it's trying to create a use that already exists. If so, then using UpdateIfExists might be appropriate, or setting FailIfExists to no, or just manually deleting that user from the system.

If it's more complicated than that, this may help (your question appears to be a duplicate of this):

[Windows msi: error 1316: the specified account already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975371/windows-msi-error-1316-the-specified-account-already-exists)

and this appears to fix some Windows issues in this area:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/mats/program_install_and_uninstall/en

Comment: I checked the wix file, can not find anything like CreateUser. If I'm not mistaken, the difference between the other stackoverflow question is that in my case the error occurs only on one server, while in the other question it happens every time. And I already tried the fix you mention (first thing I tried).

Comment: Actually, error 1316 has nothing to do with user accounts. The "secure repair" module just misinterprets the error code as a generic system error instead of the actual [MSI error](http://errco.de/msi/1316/).